# Spring Batch: Duplicate rows after job re-run

Tags: spring-batch

Our Spring Batch application is, upon restart of a failed job, processing the same records again, resulting in duplicate rows, and we want to understand how to avoid this.

The Spring Integration poller which starts the batch job is configured to run every couple of hours. When it runs a second time, the job parameters will be the same, but if the previous run failed (for example, because of a DataTruncation exception), Spring Batch will not complain that the job has already completed.

At the point of failure, several hundred thousand records will already have been processed and copied fromn the source table to the destination table. When the job is run a subsequent time, the same rows will be copied to the destination table, resulting in duplicates. Therefore, it appears that the job is not being resumed, but restarted from the beginning.

The Spring Batch database is Derby (file based), this is setup when the application starts, and it appears state is not maintained between restarts of the actual application (because a job can be run again with the same parameters). However, within one application run, state is maintained. For instance, if the job completes succesfully, the next time the poller runs an exception will be thrown because a job (with those parameters) has already completed.

Our job is definition is as follows:

```
<batch:job id="publisherJob" >
   <batch:step id="step1">
      <batch:tasklet >
    <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" processor="itemProcessor"
              writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="${...}" />
        </batch:tasklet>

        <batch:listeners>
        ...
        </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>

<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   <property name="sql" value="select ${...} from ${...} where ${...}" />
   <property name="rowMapper" ref="rowMapper" />
</bean>
```

The WHERE clause includes ORDER BY.

Our understanding was that Spring Batch would retain the state at which processing failed and proceed from that point (if the error in the source table has been fixed), therefore preventing duplicate rows. What has to be configured for this to happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch maintains state in that it remembers how many records were processed, not specifically which ones.  Because of that, it's up to you to guarantee the order of the items is reproducible from run to run so that if we process 100 records in run 1 and fail, when we skip the first 100 records in run 2, those are the right 100 records to skip.  You didn't provide the configuration for your `JdbcCursorItemReader` but my assumption is that you are not using an order by in your SQL.  If you want restartability, you need some way to guarantee the order of the items.  Using an order by in your SQL is the easiest way to accomplish this (there are others like using the process indicator pattern if that's needed).

Comment: Thanks. In our JdbcCursorItemReader we are defining an ORDER BY clause. That is why we always, in each re-run, get exactly the same rows inserted into the target table. It is always the same set that is being duplicated. Therefore it seems that Spring Batch is always starting from the first row in the source result set.

Comment: <batch:job id="publisherJob" >
   <batch:step id="step1">
      <batch:tasklet >
 <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" processor="itemProcessor"
              writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="${...}" />
        </batch:tasklet>

        <batch:listeners>
     ...
        </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>

Comment: Are you sure you're actually restarting the job or just running it again?

Comment: How do you distinguish between the two? The poller is starting the batch job for a second time. Is the only way to restart from within Spring Batch Admin?

Comment: I'd have to see your job launching configuration but there is a difference between running the job again and restarting the job.  If you are getting a new `JobInstance` in the job repository on the second time, you aren't restarting your job which means state is reset.  As a side note, can you please delete the comments above where you posted your configuration and noted that you updated the question (to keep things clean here).

Comment: In our process, we capture the identity of the rows as we process them.  When the reader initializes, it preloads a collection of row identities that were previously processed. As the reader iterates through the data retrieved for processing, it checks against the collection of row ID's and skips to the next one if there is a match.